# Push Notification using Firebase in WinForms uisng c#

Tags: c#, winforms, push-notification, firebase-notifications

I am developing an App in WinForms using C# fetching data from web APIs (JSON format). My client want push notification in my WinForms application where they will send us using Firebase push notification service, Is it possible OR there any other way to implement Push Notifications in my desktop application vai web service or otherwise. I have no idea about firebase push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Winforms in.net don't have direct support for such notifications. But yes there must be some third-party vendors who must have solutions developed for the same. Or you can also develop your own custom solutions.

I have used OneSignal API for Android Push. If you have Azure subscription then you can use Azure Notification Hub as well.

I haven't used AN Hub so can't say if they have something of your need.